Касса в значении копилка
У нас в Армении часто употребляют слово "касса" в значении "копилка".
В словарях этого значения у слова "касса" нет.
А кто-нибудь ещё употребляет это слово в этом значении или это только у нас так говорят?

"А кто-нибудь ещё употребляет это слово" Владельцы фирм так могут говорить. Все что в кассе - считай в кармане. Если считать, что каждый человек - сам себе директор, то и касса у каждого есть. Слово копилка никто, кроме может быть детей, сейчас не употребляет, разве что в переносном значении.

@user190920 с чего вдруг не употребляют? Вы в магазине сувениров как с продавцом объяснитесь? Серж, по теме: да, употребляют "касса" в значении "копилка". От пожилых слышал

@Третий глаз если мне кто-то скажет про копилку на серьезных щах, то я выпучу глаза и про себя поверчу у виска... Хотя припоминаю одного такого дядю, лет 5 назад говорил мне про копилку... странный был дядя. Другое дело подарить девочкам там брелочки хреночки всякие, копилочки сгодятся как бессмысленный, оригинальненький подарочек, ну или детям опять же. Само понятие копить вполне актуально, чего не скажешь о копилке, даже как фигуре речи ("100 рублей пойдут в копилку" - это уж совсем переносное значение, тут речь не о реальном накоплении денег).

@user190920 копилка - Ёмкость с узким отверстием для опускания монет с целью накопления, сбережения их.  Под словом копилка вы это значение имеете в виду?

@user19092 про крутить у виска это ваши субъективные тараканы. Слово есть, товар есть, люди и покупают, и слово используют, нравится вам или нет

Серж, не только это. Имею в виду чуть более широкое - место для накопления (шкаф, банку, конверт, банковский накопительный счет). Глаз, субъективизм складывается из использования языка вокруг индивида в соответствующих бытовых ситуациях, и то что он так сложился это говорит не в пользу копилки. Я не против того, что кто-то кладет деньги в шкаф или на отдельный счет, но никто при этом не говорит "копилка".

@user190920, ну про шкаф или банк — это скорее ваше личное мнение. Я имел в виду лишь ёмкость.

ну так емкость тоже никто не называет копилкой в моем окружении
